# Render documents with dynamic latex package directory

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

My client requires that I maintain separate R Libraries to prevent unexpected changes in analysis results.  In particular, I have a development library, a testing library, and a production library.

I control the use of the library in my Rmarkdown documents using the header

```
----
title: Report Name
documentclass: article
output: pdf_document
params:
  library: `path/to/development/library'
----

.libPaths(params$library)
```

This works quite well, and I'm able to render documents from the production library by calling

```
rmarkdown::render(..., params = list(library = '/path/to/production/library'))
```

So far, everything is great.  But I'm also required to maintain separate LaTeX libraries.  That means I need a way to change which library of LaTeX packages at the time I call `rmarkdown::render`, and I can't seem to find the right set of search terms to help me find how to pass a directory to use as the library when rendering the document.

Any ideas?